# How to solve offset of screenshot_share_image package in flutter (only ios)?

Tags: flutter

Hello I have an issue during long time, but not found solution. I tried to make a screenshot and share. To do this, I use the package https://pub.dev/packages/screenshot_share_image
But there is an issue when share is launch, and only if I make fall the keyboard and after I publish or cancel, I have an offset in bottom of my ios device. ( no offset with android )

This offset can be remove without close the app

[image]

It can be reproduce with package exemple :

https://pub.dev/packages/screenshot_share_image#-example-tab-

```
  import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:screenshot_share_image/screenshot_share_image.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initPlatformState();
  }

  // Platform messages are asynchronous, so we initialize in an async method.
  Future<void> initPlatformState() async {
    // Platform messages may fail, so we use a try/catch PlatformException.
    Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 5), () {
      ScreenshotShareImage.takeScreenshotShareImage();
    });

    // If the widget was removed from the tree while the asynchronous platform
    // message was in flight, we want to discard the reply rather than calling
    // setState to update our non-existent appearance.
    if (!mounted) return;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Plugin example app'),
        ),
        body: Container(
          color: Colors.red,
          child: Center(
            child: Container(
              width: 200.0,
              height: 200.0,
              color: Colors.green,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Would it be possible for you to add a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to your question, so that we can better diagnose the issue that you are experiencing?

Comment: I edit with package exemple

Comment: The package example does not work, and even if it did, its not enough to determine why you're experiencing your specific issue. You need to post a minimal recreation of your code (i.e. is that an alert dialog that is being resized, or a container? Hard to tell without code)